# Does this game require GFWL?

Tags: rage

Total Biscuit mentioned it in this video, but I think he is just plain wrong on that:

Can someone clarify if Rage has GFWL on Steam?

Comment: Since I linked a video of TotalBiscuit rambling about the steam version of Rage, I am pretty sure it is obvious that it is about pc :P And there is no GFWL on XBOX at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're talking about the PC version of RAGE, from Steam, no - this doesn't require Games for Windows Live. When I start my copy of RAGE via Steam, I get launched straight into the game without having to log into Games for Windows Live.

Comment: so that means that you could take the the game and launch it through steam, right?

Comment: if you bought it on Steam, sure... if you bought it through some other method, I'm not sure if it has GFWL (since I own my copy via Steam).

Comment: I b ought a copy from Newegg, and it had steamworks drm, so I just put the key into steam and let it download.

Comment: @Kexlox: If it has Steamworks, then it's going to be the same thing as any other Steam version, apparently with GFWL.